# Node failed register with kube-apiserver

Tags: kubernetes

Following are the steps I followed.

1. Installed and configured etcd, kube apiserver, kube controller 
   manager , kube-scheduler, flannel on master.
2. List item kubectl get nodes doesnt display any nodes initially.
3. Installed and configured flannel network, kubernetes, docker on node.When node starts up and trying to register with api server, it gives this error in journalctl -xe

   Attempting to register node 192.168.6.103
       E1222 02:20:03.487534    2030 kubelet.go:1222] Unable to register node     "192.168.6.103" with API server: the body of the request was in an     unknown format - accepted media ty
      E1222 02:20:03.490982    2030    event.go:198] Server rejected event '     &api.Event{TypeMeta:unversioned.TypeMeta{Kind:"", APIVersion:""},     ObjectMeta:api.ObjectMeta{Name:"192.168
      E1222 02:20:03.493741    2030 event.go:198] Server rejected event     '&api.Event{TypeMeta:unversioned.TypeMeta{Kind:"", APIVersion:""},      ObjectMeta:api.ObjectMeta{Name:"192.168

Following are the version installed on the node. I guess it is an issue with the node.

Docker client version - 1.10.3 API server 1.22
Docker server version - 1.10.3 API server 1.22

kubectl version gave an error

The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?

I had done this

```
$ kubectl config set-cluster demo-cluster --server=http://master.example.com:8080
$ kubectl config set-context demo-system --cluster=demo-cluster
$ kubectl config use-context demo-system
```

Then the version is displayed as

Client version,. Major 1 Minor 3
Server version Major 1 Minor 2

Anything I am doing wrong? Any suggestions would be very helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was because of version mismatch in kubectl in between the master and nodes. Minor version in master was 2 whereas in the nodes it was 3. sudo update on master and node and restarted fixed the issue.